# How deep a tableview structure can a NSFetchedResultsController manage?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have three entitites in Core Data that are arranged as follows:

Category ->> Entry ->> Field

These three entities are displayed to the user in three subsequent tableviews. The categories are shown, the user can tap on a category so all the entries in this category are shown and so on.

Currently I'm fetching all categories once in the `CategorieViewController`, sort and save them in a mutable array. Then the user taps a category, I extract this category object from the array and pass it onto the next viewcontroller. This view controller then extracts all entries of that category from the managed object's nsset and so on.

Now I though about simplifying this with an `NSFetchedResultsController`, but I'm not sure if it would even help me. As far as I know the NSFRC would for example automatically re-sort it's entries when the user renames an entry, is that correct? As of now, I'm doing this manually in the arrays that are the data source for my tableview.

Also how would a NSFRC simplify accessing the objects. I noticed it has a method to return a managed object at a given indexpath. So for example if the user tapped the 3rd category, then on the 8th entry and I now want to display the 5th field of that entry in my table view, could I just access the desired field object by providing the complete indexpath to that object?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are using the `Category` as the section header. With FRC, you can do that easily by specifying `sectionNameKeyPath` when fetching `Entry` entity.

You are correct in that you can get the entry with

```
Entry *entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The fields are accessed with

```
entry.fields;
```

which is a `NSSet`, an unordered collection. If your `Field` entity contains a sorting attribute, say, `order`, you can access an individual field with

```
Field *field = [[entry.fields filteredSetUsingPredicate:
                 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"order = %@", fieldPosition]]
                   objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you need, you can order the fields like this:

```
NSArray *orderedFields = [entry.fields sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
     @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES]]];
```